# xpath for selecting <option> html tag?

Tags: xpath, nokogiri

xpath for selecting  html tag ?

```
<select>
<option value="first option"> 1 </option>
<option value="second option"> 2 </option>
<option value="third option"> 3 </option>
</select>
```

Would below suffice ?

```
html/body/form/select[@name='options' and @value='first option']
```

Answer (score 17):

Several options here:

- `/html/body/form/select/option`
- `/html/body/form/select/option[1]`
- `/html/body/form/select/option[position() = 1]`
- `/html/body/form/select/option[@value='first option']`

All these lead to first option element

Comment: what about for select with multiple options ? how can you select more than one option ?

Comment: The first option by Rubens (shortened: `//select/option`) selects in fact all `option` tags. Also from other `select` tags, if you have more than one.

Comment: its right, andre-r; returning one or several elements depends on SelectSingleNode/SelectNodes method usage

Comment: can one select the option by what is inside the tag? eg, not with the index, [1], but something like (unsuccessfully)

//select/option[@label='1']

Comment: you can do `//select/option[. = '1']`

Answer (score 8):

Another option:

```
//select[@id='id']/option[text() = 'option text']
```

Comment: Is it possible to use trimmed values ?