# Select item from drop down list

Tags: scala, selenium

I have this `drop down list`:

```
<div class="select_id" style="width: 592px;"><span class="left"></span><span class="center">103</span><a class="select-opener"></a></div>
<select class="id-hidden" name="ids"><option value="">Please select...</option>
<option value="a">a</option>
<option value="b">b</option>
<option value="c">c</option>
<option value="d">d</option>
<option value="e">e</option>
```

So i try to select item.

So i have this element:

```
val selectAccountDropDownListElement: WebElement =
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(
    By.cssSelector(("div.select_id"))))
```

Open the drop down list:

```
selectAccountDropDownListElement.click()
```

And now how can i select an item from me `drop down list` ?

Answer (score 0):

It is as simple as ([docs](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium)):

```
singleSel("id").value = "a"
```

Or:

```
singleSel("id").selection = Some("a")
```

Comment: @davidhol it is a class that extends `Element` ([docs](http://www.artima.com/docs-scalatest-2.0.M5/org/scalatest/selenium/WebBrowser$SingleSel.html)).

Comment: How to use it ? (i didn't finf example)

Comment: @davidhol I don't use scala unfortunately. Here is what I found: the [`singleSel` implementation](https://github.com/bvenners/scalatest-selenium-dsl/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/selenium/WebBrowser.scala#L912) and some sample usages: https://github.com/bvenners/scalatest-selenium-dsl/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/scalatest/selenium/WebBrowserSpec.scala. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find the XPATH of the elements.

For example, (please check for yourself), but:

```
a_xpath = "/select/option[0]"
b_xpath = "/select/option[1]"
c_xpath = "/select/option[2]"
d_xpath = "/select/option[3]"
e_xpath = "/select/option[4]"
```

(I recommend using Firebug extension on Firefox to easily find xpaths)

Then you could click on the letter options after you opened the drop down list:

```
selectAccountDropDownListElement.click()  # opens dropdown box
driver.find_element_by_xpath(a_xpath).click()  # clicks 'a' dropdown option
```

Here's some guides that could help you. :)

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/locating-elements.html
http://www.wikihow.com/Find-XPath-Using-Firebug

Comment: I want to avoid using index number cause the list changing and so i prefer using item by name

Comment: Try:   `a_xpath = "//input[@value='a']"` or even `//select/option[. = 'a']` (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535377/xpath-for-selecting-option-html-tag)

Comment: I think i cannot reach this because the select element is hidden, see the html example

Comment: I already try it, after the click the dropdown list is open and then nothing works, maybe change this class name and remove the hidden works ? this show my another dropdown list, how can i do it via code ?

Comment: Would this work? Using the xpaths in my original answer, check the text of each element and click the one that matches what you want. `if driver.find_element_by_xpath(a_xpath).text == 'a':    driver.find_element_by_xpath(a_xpath).click()`